# Bluemix App shows Add Git for application deployed from DevOps Services Project

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, devops

Deployed an app from IBM DevOps services(IDS) project to Bluemix (which has a Git SCM attached to it), but on the bluemix app dashboard it still shows the Add Git link. When that link is clicked , a popup saying it will create the Git repo with the same name of the app and it ends up creating the DevOps Services project with a '1' suffixed to it.

So e.g. if i have a project java-test in IDS (with Git SCM) and i deploy it to BlueMix then the app dashboard in BlueMix still shows Add Git to it and clicking on that ends up creating a duplicate project named 'java-test1' in IDS. My question is shouldn't the deployment from IDS to BlueMix create and maintain that link to the Git Repo of IDS project automatically. Also, even if it is not done automatically is there a way to specify in the BlueMix project that there is an existing Git repo in IDS project for this app.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are experiencing when clicking on "Add Git" button is correct: that will create a new repository. However, if you have existing project, then you can use [Build&Deploy](https://hub.jazz.net/docs/deploy/) feature to deploy to Bluemix and configure an automatic deployment mechanism.

This should fix your issue, however if the problem persists I suggest you to open a support request using one of the following methods:

- Use the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.  After opening the support widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch, select the type of assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
- Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.

In this way the IBM Bluemix DevOps Services team will investigate your specific case in order to fix it.